# ros::package::getPath() Problem

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey there,

i've a problem using the getPath() function from roslib package. I need the package path to read out some images for a gui. In ROS Electric the code snippet below works, but since the import to ROS Fuerte I get following error while linking the package:

**...RoombaDashboard.cpp:43: undefined reference to `ros::package::getPath(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits, std::allocator > const&)'**

```
#include <ros/package.h>

...

/* Load PNGs */
wxString imgPath = wxString::FromAscii((
    ros::package::getPath("roomba_dashboard") + "/gui/").c_str());
```

Does anyone have an idea why this error occurs!? The source code seems to be right...

Thank you und best regards
Stefan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39523/ros::package::getpath()-problem/) by [Dark-Valentine](https://answers.ros.org/users/282/dark-valentine/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2012-07-23

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is solved...

It seems that the roslib package isn't a dependency of roscpp anymore. Adding the roslib package as dependency to my package makes it linkable.

**roscpp manifest.xml in electric**

```
...
<depend package="roslib"/>
...
```

**roscpp manifest.xml in fuerte**

```
<package>
  <description brief="ROS C++ client library">

...

  </description>
  <author>Morgan Quigley mquigley@cs.stanford.edu, Josh Faust jfaust@willowgarage.com, Brian Gerkey gerkey@willowgarage.com, Troy Straszheim straszheim@will$
  <license>BSD</license>
  <review status="Doc reviewed"/>
  <url>http://ros.org/wiki/roscpp</url>
  <depend package="roslang"/>
  <export>
    <cpp cflags="`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${prefix}/../../lib/pkgconfig pkg-config --cflags roscpp`"
         lflags="`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${prefix}/../../lib/pkgconfig pkg-config --libs roscpp`"/>
    <roslang cmake="${prefix}/rosbuild/roscpp.cmake"/>
  </export>
  <rosdep name="pkg-config"/>

</package>
```

Thanks anyway!

---

Originally posted by [Dark-Valentine](https://answers.ros.org/users/282/dark-valentine/) with karma: 146 on 2012-07-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 10